# Could not install package 'Microsoft.Owin 4.0.0'. Am I not able to install Microsoft.Owin packages into a .NETFramework project?

Tags: c#, .net

So I am working with `.NETFramework,Version=v4.5` and I need to use `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google` as well as `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`. However I'm getting the following error when trying to install said NuGet packages:

```
Could not install package 'Microsoft.Owin 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.
```

Is there another way to use `Microsoft.Owin` NuGet packages in a .NETFramework project?

Comment: It now requires 4.5.1. -- from: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/171

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your Framework version to v4.5.1 or later:

[image]

Comment: 'Or later' --> So I could theoretically use 4.7.2?

Comment: Yes should not be a problem